# ggplot gives "arguments imply differing number of rows" error in geom_point while it isn't true - how to debug?

Tags: r, spatial, ggplot2

I have two objects of type *Large SpatialPointsDataFrame* named **st2** and **st10**. They come from the same source. They both plot without problems with:

```
plot(st2)
```

or

```
plot(st10)
```

But I want to plot them with ggmap and ggplot. I can do this for **st2** with a simple code like this:

```
map <- get_map(location = 'Poznań', zoom = 12)
ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x =st2@coords[,1], y = st2@coords[,2]))
```

But when it comes to **st10** I get an error:

```
Error in data.frame(x = c(16.910848618, 16.910863876, 16.910913467, 16.910936356,  :   
arguments imply differing number of rows: 53885, 4
```

I check the values with length():

```
> length(st10@coords[,1])
[1] 53885
> length(st10@coords[,2])
[1] 53885
```

I check them with summary()

```
> summary(st10@coords[,1])
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  16.84   16.88   16.91   16.91   16.91   16.99 
> summary(st10@coords[,2])
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  52.35   52.41   52.46   52.44   52.46   52.46
```

What is wrong? I have over 20 of those SP data frames and some of the plot well other give the error mentioned above...this is not related to number of points

What can be wrong? Or maybe someone can give me some tips how can i debug this?

Comment: If you peruse the examples in `?ggmap` you might notice that there is not a single instance of aesthetics being mapped by any syntax other than `x = colname` where `colname` is _just_ the name of a variable. If you want to add points from another data source, you'd do something like `geom_point(data = ...,aes())`.

Comment: Okay...I tried doing it like this: `geom_point(data=data.frame(lat=st10@coords[,1], lon=lat=st10@coords[,2]), aes())` and it worked as a workaround. But I am still wondering why it is not needed with **st2**? How they are different to ggmap? Nevertheless - thank You!

Comment: What you were doing was only working because you were lucky. `aes()` does some special evaluation of its arguments that can break if you don't play by its rules. The intent of `aes()` is always to evaluate names of columns in data frames that you explicitly pass to that layer. Don't use `@` or `$` or `[` _ever_ inside of `aes()`.

Comment: ...so that's not a "workaround", it's "the correct way to do it".

Comment: Ok. So what are the custom here - should i add answer below or maybe delete the question?

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by making a new data frame.

```
tlData=data.frame(x=c(0,100000),y=c(0,1000000)
ggplot(otherdf,aes(x=X,y=Y)+geom_point(alpha=0.1)+geom_line(data=tlData,aes(x=x,y=y),color='red')
```

It seems that ggplot no longer likes have data-less geom components, as the prior version I used was perfectly okay with using aes(x=c(0,100000),y=c(0,100000).

Comment: Don't necessarily like that you have to do such workaround, but it works so +1